# 2000s era show about a group of friends who used a remote to open a portal anytime they needed to escape from aliens or creatures

Tags: story-identification, tv, isekai

From what I can remember, it's about a group of friends who used a remote to open a portal anytime they were in danger and trying to escape from aliens or creatures and would end up in another world each time they jumped through the portal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this live-action or animated? Also, can you tell us anything more about the group of friends, like how many there were, how old they were, and how many were male or female?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I think it was 6 of them 4 males and 2 females, 1 black guy I believe.

Comment: What did the aliens/creatures look like?

Comment: did one of them by any chance turn himself into a pickle at some point?

Answer (score 10):

Seems to match ‘Sliders’.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliders_(TV_series)

Many alternative realities, only they didn’t really control when and where, but had to meet the machine’s deadline, and then jump through.

The theme was friends only as thrown together, but came to depend on each other.

Comment: OMG YES this is the movie thank you so much.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted @Faith

Comment: Now, while this did have 4 male and 2 female characters, it was never more than 4 total people at once if I recall?  It started off with 3 guys and a girl, and various of them were replaced over the course of the show.  I think the black guy was the only constant for the full run?  I might've tuned out after the first few seasons...